# python stdout to file does not respond in real time

Tags: python, bash, redirect, io, pipe

Write a simple python script test.py:

```
  import time
  print "begin"
  time.sleep(10)
  print "stop"
```

In bash, run

```
python test.py > log.txt
```

What I observe is that both "begin" and "stop" appear in log.txt at the same time, after 10 seconds.

Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to flush the buffer after printing.

```
import sys
import time

print "begin"
sys.stdout.flush()

time.sleep(10)

print "end"
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Or in Python 3:

```
# This can also be done in Python 2.6+ with
# from __future__ import print_function

import time

print("begin", flush=True)
time.sleep(10)
print("end", flush=True)
```

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried calling python with the -u option, which "forces stdin, stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered" =>

```
python -u test.py > log.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because the actual writing happens only when a buffer is full, or when the file is closed. When the program ends (after 10s), the buffer is emptied, the data gets written and the file closed.